# RadGrid using OData is returning data but not displaying it

Tags: telerik, odata, radgrid

I am using a RadGrid to DataBind to an OData source. Fiddler shows that when the page is loaded a call is made to my OData source and data is returned in JSON format. The RadGrid creates the headers for each column but no data is ever displayed. My code looks exactly like what I find on the web, but nothing seems to work for me. Does anyone have any ideas with what I am doing wrong?

Here is my markup for the RadGrid:

```
            <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server">

                <MasterTableView>
                    <Columns>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" />
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="BuildingId" HeaderText="Building" />
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="Title" />
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Capacity" HeaderText="Capacity" />
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="IsActive" HeaderText="Active" />
                    </Columns>
                </MasterTableView>

                <ClientSettings>
                    <DataBinding Location="http://localhost:49937/" ResponseType="JSON">
                        <DataService TableName="Locations" Type="OData" />
                    </DataBinding>
                </ClientSettings>

            </telerik:RadGrid>
```

And this is a screenshot (via Fiddler) of the data the is being returned:

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to change the `ResponseType` from **JSON** to **JSONP**. The reason is that JSON, or any other http request initiated from javascript is restricted by the same origin policy. But RadGrid allows you to use JSONP to make remote calls to services that support the JSONP data response format.

You can refer to this article for more details

http://www.telerik.com/blogs/radgrid-for-asp-net-ajax-client-side-databinding-to-odata-services